# Modifying code in debug mode on does not reflect in flask

Tags: flask, debugging

C:\Users\eliza\PycharmProjects\hello_flask\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:\Users\eliza\PycharmProjects\hello_flask\hello.py

- Serving Flask app 'hello'
- Debug mode: on
  WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment. Use a production WSGI server instead.
- Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000
  Press CTRL+C to quit
- Restarting with watchdog (windowsapi)
- Debugger is active!
- Debugger PIN: 112-264-701
- Detected change in 'C:\Users\eliza\PycharmProjects\hello_flask\hello.py', reloading
- Detected change in 'C:\Users\eliza\PycharmProjects\hello_flask\hello.py', reloading
- Detected change in 'C:\Users\eliza\PycharmProjects\hello_flask\hello.py', reloading
- Restarting with watchdog (windowsapi)
- Debugger is active!
- Debugger PIN: 112-264-701

As above, the pycharm says that the modification is reflected, but the actual browser does not reflect when I press Refresh button.

Answer (score 0):

Try hard refresh/reload or press Ctrl+Shift+R in browser. Sometimes the HTML/JS data is saved in cache so it loads the previous cache data. but you have to load new data which is changed. for that you need to do hard reload/refresh in the browser.